# PHP Fatal error: Cannot use $this as parameter

Tags: php, this, fatal-error

I've the following PHP method which is part of the codebase which was working fine:

```
<?php
class HooksTest extends DrupalTestCase {
  public function testPageAlterIsLoggedIn() {
    $this->drupal->shouldReceive('userIsLoggedIn')
      ->once()
      ->andReturn(TRUE);
    $this->drupal->shouldReceive('drupalPageIsCacheable')
      ->once()
      ->andReturnUsing(function ($this) {
        return $this;
      });
    $page = [];
    $cacheable = $this->object->pageAlter($page);
    $this->assertFalse($cacheable);
  }
}
```

The code was passing all the CI tests before (using `phpunit`).

However now when I'm invoking the file via `php HooksTest.php`, I've got the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use **`$this`** as parameter in `HooksTest.php` on line 11
>
> Fatal error: Cannot use **`$this`** as parameter in `HooksTest.php` on line 11

I've tested with PHP 7.1, 7.2 and same issue. I believe it was working in PHP 5.6.

How can I convert above code to have the same meaning?

Does removing `$this` from the function parameter should be enough?

Comment: Use self:: maybe ?

Comment: I don't think you can pass `$this` into a function in `->andReturnUsing(function ($this) {`

Comment: This is part of the existing code which was passing all the tests, so it was not my invention. What I know it was working fine and it's failing now under PHP 7.x.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that using `$this` as the name for the parameter creates a conflict between the parameter and the `$this` referring to the object in the function scope.

Comment: It looks like it was a change implemented in 7.1: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/this_var#disable_using_this_as_parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just skip `$this` argument, change

```
function ($this) {
    return $this;
}
```

to

```
function () {
    return $this;
}
```

---

Look at *Example #5 Automatic binding of `$this`* on [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) page:

```
<?php
class Test
{
    public function testing()
    {
        return function() {
            var_dump($this);
        };
    }
}
$object = new Test;
$function = $object->testing();
$function();
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want it to work the same way it did before, you should not remove `$this` as a parameter. You should change the name of the parameter to something else, and change the corresponding variable name in the closure.

Through PHP 5.6, using `$this` as a parameter in a closure in a class method would mask the `$this` referring to the parent object. For example:

```
class Example
{
    public function test ($param) {
        $closure = function ($whatever) {      // $this not used as parameter
            return $this;                      // $this refers to the Example object
        };
        return $closure($param);
    }

    public function test2 ($param) {
        $closure = function($this) {          // $this used as parameter
            return $this;                     // $this no longer refers to Example object
        };
        return $closure($param);
    }

}

$ex = new Example;
$not_masked = $ex->test('foo');
$masked = $ex->test2('foo');

var_dump($not_masked, $masked);
```

[Working example on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uguCc)

In PHP 5.6, `$masked` would be the string 'foo', *not* the `$ex` object.

According to the output for the different versions that you can see at the 3v4l.org link, there was a brief period from 7.0.0-7.0.6 where the `$this` parameter would apparently be disregarded in favor of the object self-reference. I assume they disallowed using `$this` as a parameter in later versions to avoid the ambiguity of what `$this` actually referred to in the closure scope.

It looks like this was just confusing naming in the original code. In order to make it work as before:

```
->andReturnUsing(function ($anyOtherName) {
    return $anyOtherName;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, as previously stated by aynber, you can't pass in $this as a function param. By doing so, you're basically redeclaring it. You should just remove it as a function param.