# fatal error, cannot use $this as parameter

Tags: php

```
function thisOr($this, $or='&nbsp;'){
    return ($this!='' ? $this : $or);
}
```

this is the line of code and its saying this

> Fatal error: Cannot use $this as parameter in
>   /home/public/alumni_database/admin/incFunctions.php on line 436

Comment: You can't use `$this`, it's a reserved variable name.

Comment: you can not use `$this`. Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46348695/10302693)

Comment: problem not solved... plese use edit the above syntax for me to see exactly what you are trying to say

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of your function supplied variable.

```
function thisOr($that, $or='&nbsp;'){
    return ($that!='' ? $that : $or);
}
```

If your function is within a class the term "`$this`" is a special reserved variable and refers to the current object

*

> If you want it to work the same way it did before, you should not remove $this as a parameter. You should change the name of the parameter to something else, and change the corresponding variable name in the closure.
>
> Through PHP 5.6, using `$this` as a parameter in a closure in a class method would mask the `$this` referring to the *parent* object.

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46348982/3536236)

Comment: after changing all the $this to something else,

its giving me an error

PHP is not configured to connect to MySQL on this machine. Please see this page for help on how to configure MySQL.

What do i do here ? All files handling and linking looks corrcect

Comment: @thunderv is your function inside a class?

Comment: function thisOr($this, $or='&nbsp;'){
    return ($this!='' ? $this : $or);
}

Here is how its been declared and it gives the error

Comment: @thunderv I told you, replace `$this` with another variable name.